# Wowza Transcoder Add-on throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: wowza, transcoding, wowza-transcoder

I'm running Wowza 3.6.2 on Windows 8.1 (64 bit) and have enabled the Transcoder add-on. I'm using the transcoder to take JPEG-snapshots from the live stream. I've built a custom HTTPProvider, similar to what is described [here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?307-HTTPProvider-that-requests-a-thumbnail-image-of-a-frame-from-Wowza-Transcoder). This works fine and I can get JPG-snapshots from the stream through my HTTPProvider.

The problem is that since I enabled the transcoder I get irritating error messages in my server log on `onPublish` and `onUnPublish` of any stream.

As a transcoder template I used the default transrate.xml that comes with the Wowza installation, without any modifications made to it.

When i publish to a stream `asdf` I get errors similar to this:

```
ERROR server comment - TranscoderSessionDestination.init[livereceiver/_definst_/asdf]: [asdf_160p]:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.foo.wms.module.IncomingStreamEventHandler.getQueryStringMap(IncomingStreamEventHandler.java:191)
    at com.foo.wms.module.IncomingStreamEventHandler.onPublish(IncomingStreamEventHandler.java:83)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.MediaStream.notifyActionPublish(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.publish.Publisher.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.publish.Publisher.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.TranscoderSessionDestination.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.TranscoderSession.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.TranscoderSession.handleOnMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.LiveStreamTranscoder.handleOnMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.live.LiveStreamTranscoderRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

And when I unpublish the stream I get this:

```
ERROR server comment - TranscoderSessionDestination.shutdown: [asdf_160p]:java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.foo.wms.module.IncomingStreamEventHandler.onUnPublish(IncomingStreamEventHandler.java:166)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.MediaStream.notifyActionUnPublish(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.publish.Publisher.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.publish.Publisher.unpublish(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.TranscoderSessionDestination.shutdown(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.TranscoderSession.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.TranscoderSession.shutdown(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.transcoder.model.LiveStreamTranscoder.shutdown(Unknown Source)
    at com.wowza.wms.stream.live.LiveStreamTranscoderRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I get three of each exception when I publish/unpublish (one for each Encode block that is enabled in the transrate.xml file).

Does anyone have an idea on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my question I had another look at the stacktrace and realized what the problem was - I had been looking in the wrong direction the whole time. Since the problem appeared when I enabled the transcoder, I concluded that's where the problem must be. What I didn't realize was that `onPublish` and `onUnPublish` fires multiple times when you use the transcoder - one time for the incoming stream, and one time for every transcoded stream.

Within the `onPublish` and `onUnPublish` methods of my module I do stuff, like read querystring-paramters, which are not present on the transcoded streams. That is why the exceptions are thrown when the `onPublish` and `onUnPublish` methods are called for the transcoded streams.

To remedy this, I added two lines at the beginning of `onPublish` and `onUnPublish` methods.

```
if (streamName.contains("_"))
    return;
```

A somewhat ugly solution, but I am in control of all stream names and do not allow underscore in them anyway, so in my case this works fine.

**Update:**

*@flux has provided a much nicer solution for how to check if the stream is the result of a transcode operation. See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21099606/678801) for more info.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to determine if the stream is a transcoded stream and not a source stream

```
if(stream.isTranscodeResult()) return;
```

Comment: That is a much better solution indeed, wasn't aware of that property. I gave you a +1 for that, but I'll keep my answer as the accepted one for now, since it explain the reason for the exceptions.